# instellisense not working for just one solution (VS 2010 express for phone edition)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

[Edited] 
intellisense is not working just for just one XAML file in a particular solution (the solution compiles and runs fine)  it works on every other project and other files.. can someone point me to instructions on how to fix it ? 
I am using Visual studio 2010 express edition for windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the problem since you say it works in other projects, but Statement Completion for XAML might not be turned on in the options.

Either than that... I've had some weird problems with intellisense randomly not working at times. Most of the time deleting the intellisense database (.ncb file) so VS can rebuild it seems to work.